# issue with mysqli prepare when using LIKE clause ? PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select the first 10 results from the database where fullName LIKE 'Ma%'

it keeps returning no results. I am 100% sure that there are some results in the tables because when i run the same query without using mysqli ans it works!

what is going on with this code? is there a trick to make this code run?

here is what i have so far

```
$term = "'Ma%'";


$query = $db->prepare('SELECT customerID, fullName, birthYear, homeAddress, ID, DATE_FORMAT(idIssue, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idIssue, DATE_FORMAT(idExp, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idExp, phone
                       FROM customers WHERE (fullName LIKE ? ) LIMIT 0,10');
$query->bind_param('s', $term);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: In cases like that I always look in the MySQL log to see what is the actual query that is running against the DB.

Comment: I don't think you need to put `"'Ma%'"` in single quotes inside the string.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the term and you'l get the results.

Comment: i removed the single quote not and also before i posted this question and that did not solve the problem!  

Itay, how can i check the mysql log? i am runing SerApp on a localhost

Answer (score 3):

```
$term = "Ma%"; // <-- remove the extra quotes

$sql = 'SELECT customerID, fullName, birthYear, homeAddress, ID, phone, 
               DATE_FORMAT(idIssue, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idIssue, 
               DATE_FORMAT(idExp, "%d-%m-%Y") AS idExp
        FROM customers WHERE fullName LIKE ? LIMIT 0,10'
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('s', $term);
// s refers to a string, i for an int... etc.
$query->execute();
// I hope you have some code below this line to actually display the returned data
```

if you have any other issues with this query, they are irrlevant to the code you posted. Check for the typos, correct credentials, properly saved files and actual data.